# Exact cover using Dancing Links

Tags: c++, algorithm, knuth

After going through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518335/the-dancing-links-algorithm-an-explanation-that-is-less-explanatory-but-more-o) I tried to implement Dancing Links to solve only the exact cover problem, following is the code taken from [here](http://uaa.wtf.im/?page_id=27) and modified (It is Column-Row structure, I needed Row-Column strucuture). It works fine except that it never reaches the successful termination block in the `Search` function, I tried to trace and found that this

```
RowNode = Column->Down ; RowNode!=Column ; RowNode = RowNode->Down
```

is causing it. Example : for the following matrix

```
1 2 3 4
1 1 x x
x 1 1 x
x x 1 1
```

my code fails to `cover` the last column with `Header=4`

How can I overcome this? Here is the complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_ROW 50L
#define MAX_COL 100L

using namespace std;

struct str_node {
    struct str_node * Header;
    struct str_node * Left;
    struct str_node * Right;
    struct str_node * Up;
    struct str_node * Down;
    int HeaderID,RowIndex,ColIndex;
};


int nCol;
int nRow;
struct str_node Matrix[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
vector<struct str_node*>ResultRow;
struct str_node Root;
struct str_node *RootNode = &Root;
bool Data[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
int maxResult;

//functions to get the neighbours (are circular)
inline int dataLeft(int i) { return (i-1 < 0) ? nCol-1 : i-1 ; }
inline int dataRight(int i) { return (i+1) % nCol ; }
inline int dataUp(int i) { return (i-1 < 0) ? nRow-1 : i-1 ; }
inline int dataDown(int i) { return (i+1) % nRow ; }

void CreateToroidalMatrix(void) {

    int a,b, i, j;

    for(a = 0 ; a <= nRow ; a++) {

        for(b=0 ; b < nCol ; b++) {

            if(Data[a][b]) {

                Matrix[a][b].RowIndex = a;
                Matrix[a][b].ColIndex = b;

                // Left pointer
                i = a; j = b; do {j = dataLeft(j); } while (!Data[i][j]);
                Matrix[a][b].Left = &Matrix[i][j];

                // Right pointer
                i = a; j = b; do {j = dataRight(j); } while (!Data[i][j]);
                Matrix[a][b].Right = &Matrix[i][j];

                // Up pointer
                i = a; j = b; do {i = dataUp(i); } while (!Data[i][j]);
                Matrix[a][b].Up = &Matrix[i][j];

                // Down pointer
                i = a; j = b; do {i = dataDown(i); } while (!Data[i][j]);
                Matrix[a][b].Down = &Matrix[i][j];

                //Head pointer
                Matrix[a][b].Header = &Matrix[0][b];
                Matrix[a][b].HeaderID = b+1;

            }
        }
    }

    //Initialize root
    RootNode->Right = &Matrix[0][0];
    RootNode->Left = &Matrix[0][nCol-1];
    Matrix[0][0].Left = RootNode;
    Matrix[0][nCol-1].Right = RootNode;
}

void Cover(struct str_node *ColNode){

    cout<<"Covering header node "<<ColNode->HeaderID<<'\n';

    struct str_node *RowNode, *RightNode;

    ColNode->Right->Left = ColNode->Left;
    ColNode->Left->Right = ColNode->Right;

    for(RowNode = ColNode->Down ; RowNode!=ColNode ; RowNode = RowNode->Down) {
        for(RightNode = RowNode->Right ; RightNode!=RowNode ; RightNode = RightNode->Right) {
            RightNode->Up->Down = RightNode->Down;
            RightNode->Down->Up = RightNode->Up;
        }
    }
}

void UnCover(struct str_node *ColNode) {
    //uncover the covered nodes to find a different solution
    struct str_node *RowNode, *LeftNode;

    for(RowNode = ColNode->Up; RowNode!=ColNode; RowNode = RowNode->Up) {
        for(LeftNode = RowNode->Left; LeftNode!=RowNode; LeftNode = LeftNode->Left) {
            LeftNode->Up->Down = LeftNode;
            LeftNode->Down->Up = LeftNode;
        }
    }
    ColNode->Right->Left = ColNode;
    ColNode->Left->Right = ColNode;
}

void Search(int k){

    //all columns covered

    if( RootNode->Right == RootNode){
        cout<<"found\n";
        if(maxResult < k)
            maxResult = k;
        return;
    }

    //if not covered
    else{

        struct str_node *Column = RootNode->Right;
        struct str_node *RowNode;
        struct str_node *RightNode;
        struct str_node *LeftNode;

        Cover(Column);

        for( RowNode = Column->Down ; RowNode!=Column ; RowNode = RowNode->Down){

            ResultRow.push_back(RowNode);

            for(RightNode = RowNode->Right; RightNode!=RowNode; RightNode = RightNode->Right)
                Cover(RightNode->Header);

            Search(k+1);
            RowNode = ResultRow.back();
            ResultRow.pop_back();
            Column = RowNode->Header;

            for(LeftNode = RowNode->Left; LeftNode!=RowNode; LeftNode = LeftNode->Left)
                UnCover(LeftNode->Header);
        }
        UnCover(Column);
    }
}

void GetData(void){
    int pos,k;
    scanf("%d%d",&nCol, &nRow);

    for(int i=0 ; i<nCol ; i++)
        Data[0][i] = true;

    for(int i=1 ; i<=nRow ; i++){
        scanf("%d",&k);
        for(int j=0 ; j<k ; j++){
            scanf("%d",&pos);
            Data[i][pos-1] = true;
        }
    }
    CreateToroidalMatrix();
}

int main(void){
    GetData();
    Search(0); // from level 0
    printf("%d\n",maxResult+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't say for sure, but since you modified the structure of the matrix, you probably broke the `cover` and `uncover` functions.

Comment: thanks that looks like a cool blog. I saw many other sudoku implementations with almost same code, then when I went through Donald Knuth's original paper I realized it all started there :D

Comment: @AndyG `cover` and `uncover` are fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I went through the source code again and found the bug, forgot to increment the `nRow` in `GetData(void)`. These tiny bugs are creepy! So here are the modified parts of the code, now it works perfectly. `nRow` must be increased once because I use an extra row for the `Header` of each column.

```
void GetData(void){
    int pos,k;
    scanf("%d%d",&nCol, &nRow);

    nRow++;//this is the change

    for(int i=0 ; i<nCol ; i++)
        Data[0][i] = true;

    for(int i=1 ; i<nRow ; i++){
        scanf("%d",&k);
        for(int j=0 ; j<k ; j++){
            scanf("%d",&pos);
            Data[i][pos-1] = true;
        }
    }
    CreateToroidalMatrix();
}
```

and this loop in `CreateToroidalMatrix()`

```
for(a=0 ; a<nRow ; a++) // removed equal sign
```

Since nRow was one less than it should've been, the inline functions used to get the neighbours, specifically `dataUp()` and `dataDown()` returned unexpected values.